# my json request to send information to another site doesn't work in laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

I'm new to laravel, and I'm trying to implement a simple rest api.

I have the controller implemented.

My problem is with the POST request to send a simple json format.

```
         // Convert the merged table to JSON
        $jsonData = json_encode($jsonData);

        // send the request containing the json
        $response = Http::post('http://127.0.0.1:8082', ['json' => $jsonData]);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            // The request was successful, you can process the response here
            $responseData = 'test ok';
            return $responseData;
        } else {
            // The request failed, you can process the error here
            $responseData = $response->status();
            return $responseData;
        }
```

and This is the response I get when I send the request :

```
[THE RESPONSE 405](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbCvS.png)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm currently trying to test my request, which returns json to another site, but I'm not receiving it correctly on my site number 2. I then noticed that as soon as I put my json in my response it was set to 'null' and therefore there was no json in this request. However, when I use the json_decode function, my json decoder appears with the data I need.

Comment: What does the error response tell you about this? Usually, API endpoints provide more details about what goes wrong.

Comment: the error response tell me about the method post is not supported and it only takes the method get or head

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Why not use a GET or HEAD request then?